# which paypal account type is for credits purchases like istockphoto?

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce

i'm trying to build a paypal payment and credit card payment system with paypal.  The site that I'm trying to build is with a credits system like istockphoto and it's in php. I've seen there're a few types of payment methods from https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation#wps , but don't know which one to use.  Which one is better Express Checkout, PayPal Payments Standard, or Digital Goods Integration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe is better to question paypal staff since they know better, but in my experience the standard way to checkout with paypal is payments standard supported in many countries and currencies but don't wait for credit card checkout (virtual terminal) since is supported in limited countries, instead you should ask for international payment gateway providers for these kind of features.

hope it helped